# CakePhp disabled multiple checkbox formhelper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I have multiple checkbox, i try to disabled it, but i can't

```
$form->input('TransactionPelayananDetail.id',
array(
     'multiple' => 'checkbox', 
     'options' => $kb, 
     'div' => false,
     'label' => false,
     'data-input-id' => 'id', 
     'class' => 'checkbox left span4',
     'selected' => $kbs, 
     'readonly' => 'readonly',
     'disabled'=>'disabled'
)
);
```

any idea?

Comment: try `'disabled'=>'true'`

Comment: why both `'readonly' => 'readonly',
     'disabled'=>'disabled'` ??

Comment: i have try 'disabled'=>'true', not working, i try put both, not both, also not working

Comment: You are using very old cakephp version. I am afraid what your are trying can do with your current cakephp version by framework default way. What you are trying works great with cakephp version 2.*. If you really not wants to update your version, then you have to do this manually iterate through your data.

Comment: How to iterate it?any ideas?